# There is no Identitiy option for New Scaffolding for VS 2019 Mac

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1, visual-studio-mac, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I try to change the design of the login screen but ı couldn't add new scaffolding For Identity as you can see "Add" new scaffolding screen there is no Option for Identity.

[image]

The project template is .net core > web application with an identity.

How can ı add Identity pages to change their design?

Project Structure Like this

[image]

Comment: From the latest notes of [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-for-mac-version-8-4-is-now-available/#scaffolding) we can see, you can only add `New Scaffolding… ` with common entity. It will be added in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use this command in .Net Core CLI

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity {YOUR PROJECT NAMA}
```

For more info, visit : [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli)